# search and replace string on title key nested object vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, search

I have a nested object that includes several keys, these keys also include title and children. children is an array of the objects that have title and children keys too. (they look like a tree)
how can I  search and replace  one word  or  a part of a title's value?

```
const object = {
    id: 'uuid',
    title: 'hello You',
    type: number,
    visibility: true,
    children: [
        {
            id: 'uuid',
            title: 'You don't have any comments...',
            type: number,
            visibility: true,
            children: [{...}, {...}, ...],
            key1: {...},
            key2: [{...}]
        },
        {
            id: 'uuid',
            title: 'You your problem is not with json...',
            type: number,
            visibility: true,
            children: [{...}, {...}, ...],
            key1: {...},
            key2: [{...}]
       }
    ],
    key1: {...},
    key2: [{...}]
}
```

**search `you` and replace `world` on title**

```
output = {
    id: 'uuid',
    title: 'hello world',
    type: number,
    visibility: true,
    children: [
        {
            id: 'uuid',
            title: 'world don't have any comments...',
            type: number,
            visibility: true,
            children: [{...}, {...}, ...],
            key1: {...},
            key2: [{...}]
        },
        {
            id: 'uuid',
            title: 'world your problem is not with json...',
            type: number,
            visibility: true,
            children: [{...}, {...}, ...],
            key1: {...},
            key2: [{...}]
       }
    ],
    key1: {...},
    key2: [{...}]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using **recursive** strategy to find any key within an array and also search on their children as well.

```js
function recursive (newArray) {
  newArray.map(obj => {
    if (obj.title) {
      obj.title = obj.title.replace(/You/g, 'world')
    }
    if (obj.children) {
      return recursive (obj.children)
    }
  })
  return newArray
}
```

using the function

```js
let arr = [object]

recursive(arr)
```